# Time-lapse plot, single series, with time delay

Tags: time, wait, series

I am a complete novice! Apologies if this appears utterly basic.
I have a distribution which changes over time (cycles) and I want to show this (single series) on a dynamic plot. I have achieved it by recording a macro while I change the `yvalues` (by 1 row at a time) and then adding in a delay as follows:

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
```

However, I don't know how to define the `yvalues` range such that it will jump to the next row (of y values) and display that.
It could be up to 200 cycles.
I would like to use R3C3 type notation to define the y values and a 'for i < 200.....next i' approach, but I have tried and failed several times.
The specific issue I have is demonstrated here; see the C3:M3 changing up to C7:M7: please see attached image.

**Code issue**

[image]

Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow. You should add the tag of the programming language you are using: this will help people to find your question. You should also include your code directly in your post using [code & preformatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), instead of a screenshot.

Comment: I quote @VincentSaulue-Laborde, you should also try do improve your post by better formatting, separating the description of your tries from the specific question. Smaller sentences and more newlines.. :-)